# Robolectric, Gradle, Espresso With Flavors

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric, android-espresso, android-productflavors

I was using this [template](https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template) to incorporate robolectric tests but it's not working because I use flavors and I get this error:

```
Error:Could not find property 'testRelease' on project ':Component_Tests'.
```

How can I fix this? I'm using 2 flavors and 3 build types. Here's the gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.1+'
        classpath "com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/signing.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/build_extras.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/environments.gradle"

loadConfiguration()

apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/checkstyle.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/pmd.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/findbugs.gradle"
apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/espresso.gradle"

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('connectedAndroidTest')) {
        task.dependsOn grantAnimationPermission
    }
}

def loadPropertiesFile = { filePath ->
    def propertiesFile = file(filePath)
    def Properties properties = new Properties()

    if (!propertiesFile.canRead()) {
        throw new GradleException("cannot read " + filePath)
    }

    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile))

    return properties
}

def writePropertiesFile = { filePath, properties ->
    def propertiesFile = file(filePath)

    if (!propertiesFile.canRead()) {
        throw new GradleException("cannot read " + filePath)
    }

    properties.store(propertiesFile.newWriter(), null)
}

def loadAndStorePropertyFile = { filePath, propertyName, value ->
    def Properties properties = loadPropertiesFile(filePath)
    properties[propertyName] = value.toString()
    writePropertiesFile(filePath, properties)
    println "$propertyName is set to $value"
}

def getVersionCode = { ->
    def Properties versionProperties = loadPropertiesFile('../version.properties')
    return versionProperties['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
}

def getAlphaHash = { ->
    def Properties versionProperties = loadPropertiesFile('../version.properties')
    return versionProperties['LAST_ALPHA_HASH'].toString()
}

def getBetaHash = { ->
    def Properties versionProperties = loadPropertiesFile('../version.properties')
    return versionProperties['LAST_BETA_HASH'].toString()
}

def getReleaseCandidateHash = { ->
    def Properties versionProperties = loadPropertiesFile('../version.properties')
    return versionProperties['LAST_RC_HASH'].toString()
}

def getCurrentHash = { ->
    def cmd = "git rev-parse --short HEAD"
    def gitProcess = cmd.execute()
    def gitHash = gitProcess.text.trim()

    return gitHash
}

def getReleaseNotes = { ->
    def Properties versionProperties = loadPropertiesFile('../version.properties')
    return versionProperties['NOTES'].toString()
}

def getReleaseNotesSinceHash = { hash ->
    def cmd = "git log --pretty=-%x20[%h]%x20%s%n " + hash + "..HEAD"
    def gitProcess = cmd.execute()
    def notes = gitProcess.text.trim()

    loadAndStorePropertyFile( '../version.properties', 'NOTES', notes)
}

def copyAndRenameZipAlignedPackage = { variant ->
    def timeStamp = (int)(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
    def versionCode = getVersionCode()
    def gitHash = getCurrentHash()
    def environment = project.environment
    def file = variant.zipAlign.outputFile
    def copyTask = project.tasks.create("copy${variant.name}Apk", Copy)

    copyTask.from(file)
    copyTask.into(file.parent)

    if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        copyTask.rename(".apk", "-" + environment + "-" + versionCode + "-"
                + gitHash + "-" + timeStamp + "-RELEASE.apk");
    } else {
        copyTask.rename(".apk", "-" + environment + "-" + versionCode + "-"
                + gitHash + "-" + timeStamp + "-SNAPSHOT.apk");
    }

    variant.assemble.dependsOn copyTask
    copyTask.dependsOn variant.zipAlign
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    useOldManifestMerger true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.app’
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19

        versionCode getVersionCode()
        testInstrumentationRunner 'com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner'
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // For explicit testing with Espresso and other frameworks.
        }
        hockey {
            // For distro to stakeholders.
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }

    jacoco {
        version = '0.6.2.201302030002'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        beta.setRoot('build-types/beta')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        dev.setRoot('build-types/dev')
        hockey.setRoot('build-types/hockey')
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            debuggable true
            // still broken with dagger (espresso's dependency) as of 0.11.1
            // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix '.beta'
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.betaSigning
        }
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile 'proguard-config.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseSigning
        }

    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        removeSetAnimationScaleFromManifest(variant)

        task("generate${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
            description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
            group "Code Quality"

            def Properties localProperties = loadPropertiesFile('../local.properties')

            source = variant.javaCompile.source
            classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) +
                    files(localProperties['sdk.dir'] + "/platforms/android-4.4.2/android.jar")
        }

        copyAndRenameZipAlignedPackage(variant)
    }
}

apply plugin: 'monkey'

monkey {
    teamCityLog = false
    eventCount = 5000
    seed = 42
    failOnFailure = false
    install = false
}

apply plugin: 'hockeyApp'

hockeyapp {
    apiToken = “xxxxx”
    releaseType = 0
    notify = 0
    status = 2
    notesType = 1
    commitSha = getCurrentHash()
    notes = getReleaseNotes()
    variantToApplicationId = [
        hockeyDebug:   “xxxxx”,
        hockeyBeta: “xxxxx”,
        hockeyRelease: “xxxxx”
    ]
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(':android_ngn_stack:android-ngn-stack')
    compile project(':SlidingMenuLibrary')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    compile 'org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:0.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.6.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.9.3'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:5.9'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.0.2'
    compile("org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE") { exclude module: '*' }
    compile("org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE") { exclude module: '*' }
    compile("org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE") { exclude module: '*' }

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:" + androidAnnotationsVersion

    provided 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.example’
    }
```

Here's the test module gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:" + androidToolsBuildGradle
        classpath "com.novoda:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

test.reports.html.enabled = false     // just clean up dashboard from not generated reports
test.reports.junitXml.enabled = false // just clean up dashboard from not generated reports

apply plugin: 'android-test'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { task ->
    if (task.name == "compileTestJava") {
        task.deleteAllActions()
        println "Task $task.name is being rendered useless"
    }
}

//Note - Alphabetical order matters for projectUnderTest
android {
    projectUnderTest ':Acision_RCS_Client'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'nekohtml'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'support-v4' // crazy but my android studio don't like this dependency and to fix it remove .idea and re import project
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }

}

apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/jacoco-support.gradle"

apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/android-studio-robolectric-support.gradle"
```

Comment: Please show the full build.gradle. Now are the plugins missing.

Comment: edited the question with the module gradle file.

Comment: Well that is much stuff^^ try adding `apply plugin: 'robolectric'`.

Comment: no that won't work. The robolectric material is in another module, just like the template. Combining robolectric & espresso with gradle flavors lead me to choose that template

Comment: i never tried this template with flavors. which task exist for you? gradle has a task called `tasks` which shows available tasks, also android studio shows on the gradle tab all possible tasks.

Comment: I have tasks like 'connectedAndroidTest', 'connectedAndroidTestDevDebug', etc...Also note this error occurs while compiling.

Comment: would be nice if you create a pull request to my template project https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template with a little flavor sample. also please explain which tasks and the behaviour you expect. Then maybe I can help to get this work and I would include this to be part of the template

Comment: @nenick - I'll put it on my plate of things to do. I appreciate your offer to help and your template was a huge help in getting me to the correct spot. I have another SO ticket open with something that had multiple flavors and worked for me (Only the support libraries were not included) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130221/adding-support-library-to-robolectric-2-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use product flavours, gradle will not find the "testRelease" task. You need to use the correct naming with the flavour, e.g. testFlavourRelease (Flavour must be replaced by a existing  flavour name used in your project)

Comment: I wasn't able to create a PR...too busy. However I abandoned the template and inserted robolectric tests as their own folder outside the app folder (gradle structure). Then in settings.gradle I pulled in the correct folder which pulled in it's own gradle file for robolectric dependencies.