# Android Testing with Robolectric: not recognizing Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

We are trying to use the Robolectric testing framework in Android Studio in order to test the Facebook API. The Facebook Login button works so the Facebook API is working. However, the following test fails:

```
    package com.airportapp.test.Models;

    import android.app.Activity;

    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;
    import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
    import com.airportapp.test.MyRobolectricTestRunner;
    import com.airportapp.LoginActivity;

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

    @RunWith(MyRobolectricTestRunner.class)

    public class LoginActivityTest {
            @Before
            public void setup() {
            //do whatever is necessary before every test
            }

    @Test
    public void testActivityFound() {
            Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();

            Assert.assertNotNull(activity);
            }
    }
```

And the error is that Android Studio could not find the android.support file when we run the tests. You can see the error here: [image]

The other error that shows up is: 
android.view.InflateException: XML file app/src/main/res/layout/activity_login.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

So Android Studio is not happy with the facebook login button as well :( But it works... We think that we need to import something, but we don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

The `InflateException` is because Robolectric cannot find the resources from the Facebook SDK. To solve this, the `project.properties` file has to be updated to point to the Facebook SDK project. Do this by adding the following line to it:

```
android.library.reference.1={Path}
```

`{Path}` should be a relative path, from the project.properties file to the folder containing the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the Facebook SDK project. In my case that is `../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.android/facebook/3.21.0`.

Note that this works for all Android Library Projects which contain resources that aren't found by Robolectric. Further reading: [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1334) and [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/979). Also, more documentation about `project.properties` can be found [here](http://robolectric.org/configuring/). Note that in my project the Robolectric tests are located in the Android app project itself. So you could also try placing the `project.properties` file in the same directory as the `AndroidManifest.xml` used for testing.

As for your first problem; I have no personal experience with it. But it appears to be because Gradle cannot find the support libraries when compiling the unit tests. The answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130221/adding-support-library-to-robolectric-2-3) question should fix it.